# Trouble with Iterated Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate $\int_R
> 6y(1 − y)dydx$ where R = {$(x, y) : 0 ≤ x ≤ y ≤ 1, x ≤
> {3 \over 4}, y ≥ {1 \over2}$}

So I made the following diagram with help from Desmos: ( I hope it's clear enough)

[image]

The red is supposed to represent the domain.

When I integrated, I tried to do $$\int_0^.75\int_x^.75 6y(1 − y)dydx + \int_0^.75\int_.75^1 6y(1 − y)dydx$$

and I came out with a very wrong answer.

When I did

$$\int_.5^.75\int_x^1 6y(1 − y)dydx + \int_0^.5\int_.5^1 6y(1 − y)dydx$$

I came out with the right answer, $.08 + .25 =.33$

Can somebody please give me a full explanation as to why the second method and not the first is valid? I am trying to understand the general rule here for how to do this type of integration.

Comment: True enough, your first approach is wrong.  I believe **both** integrals have the wrong bounds in your first stab.

Comment: Ok, would there be a more correct way of doing what I tried to do in the first approach, or is the second approach the only correct one?

Comment: It's likely the only sensible way if you're going $y$ first $x$ second.  You could, of course, reverse this.

Comment: It seems like the second integral of the first approach is correct, and my only mistake is that in the first integral I used $x$ instead of $\textrm{max}(0.5, x)$. Indeed when I correct that, I get $.212891 + .117187 = .33$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the first integral of first attempt, namely $\int_0^.75 \int_x^.75 6y(1-y)\text{d}x \text{d}y$, it seemed you wanted to represent lower trapezoid. But your region declaration, which is $0 < x < 0.75$, and $x < y < 0.75$ results in triangle. $y$ must be greater than $0.5$, so correct region is $0 < x < 0.75$ and $\textrm{max}(0.5, x)<y<0.75$.

Unfortunately, it is quite awkward to represent such region a by nested integral form in given order. (Have you ever seen $\int_{\textrm{max}(0.5,x)}^{0.75}$ kind of thing?) So, reversing the order of nested integral makes sense: $0.5 < y < 0.75$ and $0 < x < y$. You can see [y inside order](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3Cx%3C0.75,%20x%3Cy%3C0.75,%201%2F2%3Cy) and [x inside order](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.5%20%3C%20y%20%3C%200.75,%200%20%3C%20x%20%3C%20y) coincide that way.

So your proper integral should be $\int_.5^.75 \int_0^y 6y(1-y) \text{d}x \text{d}y$. Of course, plus second term.

Comment: Can you please explain a little more why with my first method I would need to use $\textrm{max}(0.5, x)$, whereas in the second method with the first integral I had no problem with just using $x$, and I did not have to account for the fact that $y$ must be greater than 0.5?

Comment: Is it because in the first method, I am integrating $x$ from 0 to .75, so I am by default including all the regions of $x$ that are below the 0.5 on $y$, whereas in the second method I am only starting $x$ from 0.5, so already when I start off I am excluding anything below 0.5 on $y$?

Comment: @agbit Exactly. $\textrm{max}(0.5,x) < y$ is maybe too compact. These are separate two conditions each: $0.5 < y$ and $x < y$, just written in one form. In second method, the condition $0.5 < y$ exists too and can be written as $\textrm{max}(0.5,x) < y$ too. However, since $0.5 < x$ already holds in the integral, $x < y$ is enough and $0.5 < y$ part can be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt is integrating over [this region](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3Cx%3Cy%3C0.75) plus [this region](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3Cx%3C0.75%3Cy%3C1), which includes an area below the $y=\frac{1}{2}$ line that shouldn't be there.

Comment: I can't figure out how to get WΑ to plot both regions on the same graph.